# Подгон координат различных масштабов

Tags: масштабирование, координаты, c++

Доброго времени суток и сразу к делу! Есть карта с неизвестным масштабом и есть координаты соответствующие масштабу 1:1. Как подогнать имеющиеся координаты к карте с меньшим масштабом?

Comment: Что делать, если мне не известны максимальные координаты для карты? У меня есть лишь координаты 1:1 и карта с неизвестным мне уменьшены масштабом!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен с [@Free_ze](/users/16651/free_ze), банальная пропорция. Допустим, есть некоторая величина x в интервале [a;b]. Эта величина откладывается относительно начала интервала, т.е. x-a. Чтобы перевести ее в другую систему, например, найти некоторую величину t в интервале [w;v], необходимо ее нормировать, т.е. привести к интервалу [0;1]: x'=(x-a)/(b-a).

Теперь обратная операция, "развернем" нормированную величину в целевом интервале - надо теперь умножить на ширину интервала и прибавить смещение: t=x'*(v-w)+w. Заметьте, все правильно работает (не заморачивайтесь со знаками!), даже если интервал перевернут, т.е. начало больше конца в абсолютных величинах.

Остается сделать две вещи:

1. определить, что известно, а что нет;
2. подставить выражения друг в друга и реализовать на вашем языке, каким бы он ни был.

Примечание: в любых задачах есть тот набор исходных данных, который необходим для решения, а если их недостаточно, то задача не решается или имеет не одно, а множество решений. Вашу задачу трудно понять даже с учетом комментариев.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло. Осталось лишь найти крайние точки в игре и на карте :)

Answer (score 0):

Банальная пропорция же. Нужно знать размер искомого пространства. Рассмотрим точку на карте. Ее координата X так относится к размеру начальной карты (1:1) по горизонтали maxX, как некоторая пропорциональная искомая координата ? к размеру новой карты по горизонтали maxXNew. Получается пропорция: x/maxX = ?/maxXNew => ? = x * maxXNew / maxX. Аналогично с Y.

```
// Максимальные значения для старого и нового пространства
// (предполагается, что начало находится в 0).
const double MAX_OLD_X = 5;
const double MAX_OLD_Y = 5;
const double MAX_NEW_X = 10;
const double MAX_NEW_Y = 10;

struct Point {
    double X,Y;
    Point(double x, double y) : X(x),Y(y) {}
};

Point convert(Point old) {
    return Point(
            old.X * MAX_NEW_X / MAX_OLD_X,
            old.Y * MAX_NEW_Y / MAX_OLD_Y);
}
```

Comment: С этим разобрался, что делать если центр смещен и тоже не известно на сколько. Но есть вспомогательная информация, а именно: координаты нескольких точек в соответствии с масштабом 1:1 и 1:?